# JSON data not displayed using getJSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
$('document').ready(function() 
    { 
        $.getJSON('news.php', parseInfo);
});

function parseInfo(data)
{
    alert(data.news);//undefined
    $('#info').html(data.news);
}
```

My PHP output(news.php) is `[{"id":"20110428","news":"april 28 2011"}]`

Comment: Always give upvote to the genuine answer that really helps you, and finally select the best suited answer as correct one... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your object is wrapped inside an array.

You need `data[0].news`

Alternatively remove the outer square brackets from your JSON output.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that's an array so you probably want to do the following:

```
alert(data[0].news);
```

Comment: I think Alnitak was first, you should probably accept his answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your output is an array with a JSON element. either remove the `[]` or point to (guessing here) `data[0].news`

Comment: You are right Nanne.....i took array of array !
<?php
include_once("connect.php");
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
 $date = $_GET['id'];
}
else{ 
$date = date("Ymd");
}
$sql = "SELECT id,news FROM daily WHERE id = '$date'";
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die("Query failed");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
 $data['id'] = $row['id'];
 $data['news'] = $row['news'];
 //$arr[] = $data;this is where i made the mistake
}
//print_r($arr);
$json_data = json_encode($data);
echo $json_data;
?>